# Rails 4 best practice for API

Tags: json, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an API onto a web app, and I have a few questions on how it should be set up.

Certain records cannot be created through the web app itself, but the API can have full control of not only creating, but other web-app functionality as well.

Let's say I have 3 rails objects: *User* `has_one` *Business* `has_many` *Ratings*

In the web app, the user has full CRUD control over *Users* and *Businesses*, but only RUD control for the *Ratings* (no create).

In the API, there is full CRUD control of all three objects.

So, with this being said, how should I structure my files? At first glance, one would think that I would create normal controllers for all three objects and just restrict the "Create" event in `receipts_controller.rb` for JSON access (API). However, if I use namespaces for my API ( myapp.com/api/v1/receipt.json ), wouldn't I need a separate controller for my receipt object?

While writing this, I got the idea to just namespace the API like normal and have the `/api/v1/receipts_controller.rb` file extend the normal `/receipts_controller.rb` -- would this be the correct approach?

Obviously I do not want to have the web-app and API running off of different controllers, which is why I'm seeking some advice on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your explanation. Here is my 2cents. I prefer to have separate controllers for API and he Web App.
For couple of reasons:

1. when you start to releasing the new versions you don't want to change the web app controller also you don't want to have too many if conditions. This is pure evil. All you need is making the `~/v2/~` and put all the logics there.
2. Skinny Controller is the key, mixing both API and Web App Controller makes it harder to debug your controller and you might end up too many methods
3. Having different controller for API gives you the ability to enforce different security policy on it and leave your web app alone.